# avoid hyphenation in chapter title using tikz and titlesec

Tags: tikz-pgf, chapters, titlesec, hyphenation

[This question is similar to [the one here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35686/avoid-hyphenation-in-chapter-title), but the solutions given there do not work in my context]

In a (fairly complex) book I'm using `titlesec` and `tikz` to produce fancy chapter headings, basically using the following code

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\sffamily}{\scalebox{3}{\thechapter}}{25pt}{\Huge\chaptitle}
%                        left before after
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{110pt}{20pt}
% set the style of the chapter title as a tikzpicture, 
% filled using the current partcol2 color
\newcommand{\chaptitle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[fill=gray!20,inner sep=6pt,text width=\dimexpr\linewidth-12pt\relax] {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

However, in several chapters, the chapter title gets hyphenated like this image

[image]

I tried to make a simple MWE to demonstrate this, but for some reason it doesn't hyphenate the word 'Table' in this simple example. (The `krantz.cls` is that used by my publisher to set page dimensions.)  FWIW, here it is:

```
%\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\documentclass[10pt,krantz2]{krantz}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}     %% extended color models; load before tikz
\usepackage{tikz}             %% used for hyp3way.tex and chapter vtocs

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\sffamily}{\scalebox{3}{\thechapter}}{25pt}{\Huge\chaptitle}
%                        left before after
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{110pt}{20pt}

\newsavebox{\chaptocbox}

% set the style of the chapter title as a tikzpicture, 
% filled using the current partcol2 color
\newcommand{\chaptitle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[fill=gray!20,inner sep=6pt,text width=\dimexpr\linewidth-12pt\relax] {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter[Mosaic Displays for n-way Tables]{Mosaic Displays for n-way Tables}\label{ch:mosaic}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

This gives:
[image]
One suggested solution was to manually break the title, e.g.,

```
\chapter[Mosaic Displays for n-way Tables]{Mosaic Displays for n-way\\ Tables}\label{ch:mosaic}
```

This does have the desired effect, however, it screws up the use of the chapter title in the running heads of the subsequent pages.

So, I'm looking for some way to modify the `\titleformat` or `\chaptitle` commands to say do-not-hyphenate.  I did try adding `\sloppy` to the `\titleformat` command.

Comment: Try `font=\raggedright` in `\node[fill=gray!20,inner sep=6pt,text width=\dimexpr\linewidth-12pt\relax,font=\raggedright] {#1};` As I can't reproduce the issue, I can't add an answer now.

Comment: Not tested, but I think that `\chapter{Mosaic Displays for n-way \mbox{Tables}}` won't hyphen `Tables`.

Comment: `\chapter{Mosaic Displays for n-way \mbox{Tables}}` works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @HarishKumar Can you add an answer?

Comment: @egreg: Done. Thanks and happy new year. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `tikz` nodes for the chapter titles, you may use `tikz` ways to have ragged right text inside that node. This is done by adding  `font=\raggedright` to the `node` options:

```
\node[fill=gray!20,inner sep=6pt,text width=\dimexpr\linewidth-12pt\relax,font=\raggedright] {#1};
```

so that the definition becomes:

```
\newcommand{\chaptitle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[fill=gray!20,inner sep=6pt,text width=\dimexpr\linewidth-12pt\relax,font=\raggedright,] {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```